# How to use "this" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have some duplicate code like below, I want remove the duplicate code, to achieve "DRY" (Do not Repeat Yourself) principle. Anybody can help me out will be great appreciated!

Javascript code is like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".adjustLineFeedProductName").ready(function () {
            var str = "";
            for (i = 0; i < $(".adjustLineFeedProductName").html().length; i += 66) {
                str = str + "<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">" + $(".adjustLineFeedProductName").html().substring(i, i + 66) + "</p>";
            }
            $(".adjustLineFeedProductName").html(str);
        });

        $(".adjustLineFeedQuantityPerUnit").ready(function () {
            var str = "";
            for (i = 0; i < $(".adjustLineFeedQuantityPerUnit").html().length; i += 66) {
                str = str + "<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">" + $(".adjustLineFeedQuantityPerUnit").html().substring(i, i + 66) + "</p>";
            }
            $(".adjustLineFeedQuantityPerUnit").html(str);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Html code is like below:

```
<div class="elaborate" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 3px 10px;"><b class="adjustLineFeedProductName"><%: (string)Model.Product.ProductName %></b></div>
<div class="elaborate" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 3px 0px 0px 10px;"><span class="adjustLineFeedQuantityPerUnit">Quantity/Unit : <%: (string)Model.Product.QuantityPerUnit %></span></div>
```

I want using below Javascript to instead above Javascript, but it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".adjustLineFeed").ready(function () {
            var str = "";
            for (i = 0; i < this.html().length; i += 66) {
                str = str + "<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">" + this.html().substring(i, i + 66) + "</p>";
            }
            this.html(str);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried using below html code instead above html code, but it is not working:

```
<div class="elaborate" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 3px 10px;"><b class="adjustLineFeed"><%: (string)Model.Product.ProductName %></b></div>
<div class="elaborate" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 3px 0px 0px 10px;"><span class="adjustLineFeed">Quantity/Unit : <%: (string)Model.Product.QuantityPerUnit %></span></div>
```

Comment: `this` is a native DOM element, you'll have to wrap it -> `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a jQuery block, `this` will refer to the `HTMLDomElement` instance. On this you can do DOM like operations such as `innerHTML` etc, but obvious you can't do jQuery methods as.. it isn't a jQuery object.

To create a jQuery object, pass the DOM element to `$` like so;

```
$(this)
```

---

Some other points;

1. `$(".adjustLineFeedProductName").ready()` is meaningless. A `span` or a `br` is *never* `ready`; I'm suprised this even works. Having your code inside a `$(document).ready()` is enough. What you probably want is to use `jQuery.each()` so you can target *all* instances of `.adjustLineFeedProductName` and `.adjustLineFeedQuantityPerUnit` on your page (if there is only one instance, consider an ID instead).

   ```
   $(".adjustLineFeedProductName").each(function () {
       var str = "";
       for (i = 0; i < $(this).html().length; i += 66) {
           str = str + "<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">" + $(this).html().substring(i, i + 66) + "</p>";
       }
       $(this).html(str);
   });
   ```
2. Cache the response of `$()`. `$(this)`. `$()` does work behind the scenes each time you call it. Whilst it's not a great deal of work for `DOMElements`, it's a good practice to get into the habit of caching these. jQuery selectors, for example, perform DOM lookups which aren't trivial.

   ```
   $(".adjustLineFeedProductName").each(function () {
       var str = "";
       var self = $(this); // cache

       for (i = 0; i < self.html().length; i += 66) { // use self
           str = str + "<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">" + self.html().substring(i, i + 66) + "</p>"; // use self
       }
       self.html(str);
   });
   ```
3. Similar to #2, cache `html()` as well, for the same reasons.

   ```
    $(".adjustLineFeedProductName").each(function () {
       var str = "";
       var self = $(this); // cache
       var html = self.html();

       for (i = 0; i < html.length; i += 66) { // use self
           str = str + "<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">" + html.substring(i, i + 66) + "</p>"; // use self
       }
       self.html(str);
   });
   ```

Comment: `$(this)` doesn't do a "DOM lookup" if `this` is a DOM Element already, it just wraps that element in a jQuery object.

Comment: @Alnitak: Eugh you're right. This is why I shouldn't answer SO questions on a weekend... :P.

Comment: @Matt it's still a good idea to cache the object, though, of course.  And you should cache `html.length` too, while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

the right code would be like this:

```
$(this).html()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
this.html(str);
```

to this:

```
$(this).html(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "Matt" !!! I modified the code as your suggested, it works perfect!!!

Javascript code is like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".adjustLineFeed").each(function () {
            var str = "";
            var self = $(this); // cache
            var html = self.html();
            for (i = 0; i < html.length; i += 66) {
                str = str + "<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">" + html.substring(i, i + 66) + "</p>";
            }
            self.html(str);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html code is like below:

```
<div class="elaborate" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 3px 10px;"><b class="adjustLineFeed"><%: (string)Model.Product.ProductName %></b></div>
<div class="elaborate" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 3px 0px 0px 10px;"><span class="adjustLineFeed">Quantity/Unit : <%: (string)Model.Product.QuantityPerUnit %></span></div>
```